# In C++, what is "^" symbol means? except XOR

Tags: c++, syntax, c++-cli

I read an article about C++ language. There is lines using "^", not XOR.
Sample code is like:

```
array<String^>^args = System::Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: That line is C++/clr (cli) which is no C++

Comment: It is a C++ extension syntax for managed code.  Equivalent to `*` but for garbage-collected objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol ^ is used for managed pointers.
Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxx6f46y.aspx , for more information about them.

They are from C++/CLI though and not C++.

Comment: And managed pointers aren't in C++ at all.

Comment: It is C++/clr as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Yes,and C++/CLI is not C++. Just thought you should mention what language it really is.

Comment: @Deduplicator ok, changed.